# Sitecore 8 SOLR Indexing manager error (__display_name_t)

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8

I am using Sitecore 8 SP 4
and try to work with SOLR, I have done everything like described here 
[Configuring Solr for use with Sitecore 8](https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/search/solr/Configuring-Solr-for-use-with-Sitecore-8/) and I am try to reindex data
rebuilding looks like starting work but after some time I see next error

```
    Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">1</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">ERROR: unknown field '__display_name_t'</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
 ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Post(String relativeUrl, String s)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.SendAndParseHeader(ISolrCommand cmd)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 group, Int32 groupSize)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.Commit()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.PerformRebuild(Boolean resetIndex, Boolean optimizeOnComplete, IndexingOptions indexingOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.Rebuild(Boolean resetIndex, Boolean optimizeOnComplete)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

what does __display_name_t field do ? how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you put the proper `schema.xml` in every Solr core?

You should be able to find a line:

```
<dynamicField name="*_t" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

In your `schema.xml`. If it is there, try to restart Solr server.

Here is a nice blog post describing [how to configure Sitecore to work with Solr](http://www.sequence.co.uk/blog/sitecore-8-and-solr/).

Comment: I don't know why but this specific like was lose. Thanks you